# Diophantine equation: $13^x+3=y^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations, unique-factorization-domains

$x,y$ are positive integers.

$$13^x+3=y^2\iff \left(4+\sqrt{3}\right)^x\left(4-\sqrt{3}\right)^x=\left(y+\sqrt3\right)\left(y-\sqrt3\right)$$

$\gcd\left(y+\sqrt3, y-\sqrt3\right)=1$, therefore $y+\sqrt3=\left(4+\sqrt{3}\right)^x$ (implies $x=1$), since $\Bbb Z\left[\sqrt{3}\right]$ is a UFD and $4+\sqrt{3}$ is prime (since $4^2-3=13$ is prime) and $y-\sqrt{3}$ has negative $\sqrt3$ part.

> My question: why can't RHS have units, e.g. $y+\sqrt3=\left(2+\sqrt3\right)\left(4+\sqrt{3}\right)^x$.

(then $y-\sqrt3=\left(2-\sqrt3\right)\left(4-\sqrt{3}\right)^x$)

Solution found in *Introduction to Diophatine Equations* by Andreescu Titu (page $315$).

Comment: $x=0$ and $x=1$ are the only solutions.

Comment: I suspect the author had $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ in mind. Here the Euclidean norm may be taken as $N(a+b\sqrt{-3})=a^2+3b^2$, and it is clear that the only units are $\pm 1$.